# Importing Image pixels as array in C++ using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I just want to know , I want to import image pixels as a matrix form using C++  in Eclipse.
Can any one help me how to import the image pixels in eclipse in matrix form
and help me write the begining of the code?

Comment: What did you try so fat and what is the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by fat?

Comment: @KhanzadaNawabOmarMuhammadHu Questions on this site usually get a better reaction if you add some code examples of the options you've tried, and the issues you are facing.

Comment: Actually I am new but I want to post my code here.. but all it comes in single line how can i post it that it would be readable for you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help